# using Powershell to copy a directory (and subdirectory(s)) withouth overwriting/removing files

Tags: powershell

Working on a bit of a personal project.
I have my music collection on 3 different drives (read: different machines) including my NAS, Laptop, and Desktop. I need to be able to add new files to any of those 3 devices and have them sync upon request.

I have been attempting to use Robocopy.exe as it is a super easy one-liner to impliment, but it does not copy sub-folders/directories.

I am, i should mention, also pretty new to Powershell. The command does not need to be a one-liner, so if there is a way to impliment multi-level recursion to robocopy.exe all folders in a main directory, this would also work.

what i have now:

```
[string]$c = "c:\users\$env:username\music"
[string]$z = "z:\music"
robocopy.exe $c $z
robocopy.exe $z $c
```

i have a .cmd in my shell:startup to call execute this script 60 seconds after boot, and it works amazing for normal music files. The problem is, alot of my songs are in an album folder (such as Led Zeppelin box set) that would not make sense to scatter.

Any help would be much appreciated, as i have not found a good powershell method of copy/paste w/o exclusion / overwrite in the last few days freetime.

extra note: my two machines are running windows 10 so i will have access to latest powershell/ISE

Comment: Do you need deletions to sync too, or only additions?

Comment: only additions, i would like to be able to add files to any of the three locations and copy them to the others (i've been doing this with a script on my PC and one on my Laptop) @TrippKinetics

Comment: (?) Robocopy can copy subdirectories. People do this all the time.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart would you care to tell me how then? Because i could not figure out how to make this work.

Comment: Type `robocopy /?` for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to list the files in both locations and compare the lists.  Then you iterate the list of differences.

```
$Folder1Contents = Get-ChildItem $Folder1Path
$Folder2Contents = Get-ChildItem $Folder2Path
$FolderDiffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Folder1Contents -DifferenceObject $Folder2Contents

$FolderDiffs | foreach {
    $copyParams = @{
        'Path' = $_.InputObject.FullName
    }
    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=')
    {
        $copyParams.Destination = $Folder2Path
    }
    else
    {
        $copyParams.Destination = $Folder1Path
    }
    Copy-Item @copyParams
}
```